# init block blocked constructor?

Tags: java, constructor, initialization

I was trying to test the working of init blocks and constructors in Java. When an object is created, the init block is executed first; then the constructor is executed. And if no user-defined constructor is provided, then the compiler provides a default constructor. I have tried the following code:

```
class A
{int a;
 public static void main(String arr[])
{A a1=new A();
  System.out.println(a1.a);
}  }
```

The output of this program is 0, which is very obvious; but, when I tried the following program:

```
class A
    {int a;
//init block
{a=12; }
     public static void main(String arr[])
    {A a1=new A();
      System.out.println(a1.a);
   }  }
```

I got the answer 12, but according to the execution flow, the init block (which set a=12) should execute first, then the constructor. Here the default constructor should be executing after the init block, and the value of a should be 0. Why is the value of a 12?

Comment: Why would the value be 0?  `a`, if unassigned, would default to 0, but it is not unassigned.  It is given a value of 12 in the initialization block.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the value of A in main method after creation of new instance of `A`. So it is already set up (if not, you cant access variable of "non-created" object, right?)

---

If you want test the value of variable `a` IN creation, run this code

```
class A {

    public A(){
        System.out.println("The value of a in constructor is: " + a);
    }

    int a;
    {
        System.out.println(a);
        a = 12;
        System.out.println(a);
    }

    public static void main(String arr[]) {
        A a1 = new A();
    }
}
```

It has this output :

```
0
12
The value of a in constructor is: 12
```

Answer (score 0):

Init blocks run after field initialization. Thus, init blocks will always see the field values after any default or initial values are set. Java isn't going to somehow set the field values after your init code runs - that would make init blocks pointless.

Constructors run after init blocks, but note that the Java default constructor does nothing.